# Is there a module to run NodeJS after calling localhost in the address bar

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I know if we install the pm2 module with the [pm2-windows-startup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-startup) utility, it will run NodeJS automatically on Windows startup. But is there a similar module to run NodeJS after we typed `localhost` in the address bar of the browser and clicked Enter? I mean if I use

```
}).listen(80, 'localhost');
```

So there is no need to specify any trailing port in the address bar

ps. Please don't forget that according to [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), we can ask here not only about *"a specific programming problem"* but also about *"software tools commonly used by programmers"*

Answer (score 1):

There is no module that allows this functionality. In this scenario, it's the browser which needs to start `node` in the background, which is problematic due to security reasons.

The closest thing that allows you to run external programs from the browser are [custom protocols](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-How-to-launch-external-applications-using-custom-protocols-rock-instead-of-http-).

If you're willing to go through the setup, you should be able to write something like this in the browser address bar:

```
myapp://localhost
```

which would allow the browser to start node for you.